# create equal part of imploded strings from array

Tags: php, loops

Lets say I have a array of 120 items. I need to separate them into comma separated texts in equal chunks.

For example if I choose to separate all elements to chunks of 50 / 120 items should be separated as 50, 50 and 20.

I tried below code:

```
$lines = file("all.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$allarr[] = array_chunk($lines, 50);


foreach($allarr[0]  as $chunks);
{
    $str = implode($chunks,",");

    echo $str."<br><br>";
 }
```

The above code create the correct chunks of array. But When I want to loop it  and add implode. It just prints the last array.

EDIT : For easy understanding below is the example

```
$lines = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$allarr = array_chunk($lines, 3);
var_dump($allar);

foreach($allarr as $chunks);
{

var_dump($chunks);
$str = implode($chunks,",");

}
```

Where `$allar` output is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

But  `$chunks` output is only last part of array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: Don't remove your original code from the question, then the answers make no sense. If you want to show what you've tried since then, add it as an addition to the question.

Comment: EDIT : i have added easy example

Comment: You have an extra `;` after `foreach($allarr as $chunks)`. That's making the loop body empty, and you're doing `var_dump($chunks)` after the loop is done.

Comment: @Barmar Good point, you also have not applied the inner loop as per my answer! And you are not looking or at least answering anything in the CHAT session.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : inner loop is unncessary...Removing semicolon did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `;` that's ending the `foreach` loop early.

```
foreach ($allarr as $chunks);
                            ^
```

So you're doing nothing in the `foreach` loop, and then doing `var_dump($chunks)` after the loop is finished. That's why it only shows the last chunk.

Get rid of that `;` and it will work correctly.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/V1lcmZ)